# Read content from Java GUI without having the source code

Tags: java, c#, automation, flaui

I want to read content in a Java program which uses Java GUI as the frontend. Usually I would do this with FlaUI in C# but since Java GUI is not mainly a Windows Application, I can't use FlaUI on it. I don't need to invoke buttons or click in the screen, but I need to read information so my program can create logs to it.

The Java program looks like this:

[image]

I need to read the COM Port, if the "Rmv" checkbox is checked and the "min" value. I know it's possible to do using library like SikuliX but I can't let the Java program in first layer all the time because I need to use the computer and I need to get informations every 5 seconds. I can use any commom language to do this automation program (C, C#, C++, Python, Java, JS..), I just need a help to find the way to do this.

Comment: Maybe does not fit to your purpose but, there are tools for Java platform which can connect, inspect and retrieve contents of its heap memory directly from running programs, like visualvm or flight recorder.

Comment: @MNEMO Yeah that's not what I'm looking for. I have already searched a lot and no lucky. I would like to know why there are so many solutions to automate windows application but absolutely no solutions to Java apps.

Comment: Because that's a _very_ hacky way to go about things. _Maybe_ it's worthwhile to investigate how that Java program gets its data and try and tap into the source or play middleman or something like that.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods That's a really good idea, I'm already developing by this way. Btw I believe I have made a really valid question, explaining what I need, what I have already figured out just trying to expand my knowledge and someone gives -1 rep just to harm me. It's not the first time this happens. If someone can explain what's not good in my question, I would be thankful and improve next time.

Comment: Do you know what Java GUI framework was used to make this?